# how to run a script on loading a webpage

Tags: javascript

how can i get this script to run on loading a webpage , without pressing a button

```
    $(document).on('ready', function() {

    $('#findme').on('click', function() {    
    $('#message').html('Loading...');    
      $.ajax( {
        url: "https://api.mercadolibre.com/geolocation/whereami",
        success: function(data) {
          var city = data.city_name;
          var country = data.country_name;
          $('#message').text("You are in " + city + ", " + country + '!'); 
          }

      });
  });

});
```

Comment: have you tried trigger()? https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: just use "window.onload = function() {
functionNameOfFunctionWhichShouldRunOnPageLoad(param1, param2,...);
};"

Comment: No, i've tried window onload and <body onload=,  and did not work,

Comment: what output do you get with "$(document).ready( function () {
 functionNameOfFunctionWhichShouldRunOnPageLoad();
}"

Comment: i am trying to run this http://codepen.io/adamrifai/pen/VYNVEM

Comment: You can put it in a function and call that function in html <body onload-="functionname()"/>

Comment: yes...but you are adding a button after the document is ready....just skipp the buttonpart and directly print the message after status "ready" .... btw: adam, have you tried eves way...or dont you trust her since the apple incident   ;)

Comment: that's true, no need for the button,, and without Eve I won't be Adam :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this, its your code only i removed button on click function so it will execute on document ready function

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {

$('#message').html('Loading...');    
  $.ajax( {
    url: "https://api.mercadolibre.com/geolocation/whereami",
    success: function(data) {
      var city = data.city_name;
      var country = data.country_name;
      $('#message').text("You are in " + city + ", " + country + '!'); 
      }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a function and call it in desired events... [Check working demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPmeOx)

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  geo();
});

$('#findme').on('click', function() {    
   geo();
});

function geo(){

  $('#message').html('Loading...');    
      $.ajax( {
        url: "https://api.mercadolibre.com/geolocation/whereami",
        success: function(data) {
          var city = data.city_name;
          var country = data.country_name;
          $('#message').text("You are in " + city + ", " + country + '!');  
        }
      });

}
```